build pytorch dataset from single large json file
I have a large json file (>10GB) for training on a 2-node GPU. The dataset is used to build a data loader:
...
sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
    dataset, num_replicas=world_size, rank=rank)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,
                                          batch_size=micro_batch_size,
                                          sampler=sampler,
                                          shuffle=False,
                                          num_workers=num_workers,
                                          drop_last=drop_last,
                                          pin_memory=True,
                                          collate_fn=task_collate_fn)
...

How to build a dataset from single large json file that can be used by distributed sample rand data loader? Reading file content from disk to memory is not possible here.
